# How do I remap control-shift-leftmouse in gvim?

Tags: vim, mapping, macvim

I'd like to remap a modified click in gvim (and also MacVim), but certain combinations of modifiers work while others do not. In gvim on a Linux box, I would like to insert "hello" anywhere I type:

```
:noremap <C-S-LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>ihello<ESC>
```

However, that command does not work: control-shift-click retains its original behavior. Yet I *can* remap control-click in gvim:

```
:noremap <C-LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>ihello<ESC>
```

In MacVim, command-shift-click `<D-S-LeftMouse>` is likewise unresponsive, as are most other modified clicks.

How can I actually remap the modified mouse clicks?

Comment: Name-twin :) good catch. I have no clue, but I can confirm your findings on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double modifier keys don't work in MacVim. It's a known limitation/bug.

```
:nnoremap <M-LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>ihello<Esc>
```

seems to work, though, but neither `<C-LeftMouse>` nor `<D-LeftMouse>` do.

`<C-LeftMouse>` brings the normal contextual menu everyone expects, I wouldn't count on it being easily changed.

`<D-LeftMouse>` does nothing at all. I wonder if it's even registered.

Comment: Ah, alas. No `<D-{Mouse}>` events are mentioned in the macvim docs; only modified keys.

Comment: I guess "it can't be done" is a legitimate answer (accepted). The MacVim author also confirms that <D-Mouse> is not implemented.

Answer (score 4):

To remap the `<C-LeftMouse>` in MacVim, you should first disable the contextual menu:

```
defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMTranslateCtrlClick 0
```